# Android crashes: Async error #2

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have searched multiple times for this problem but I haven't found a solution. I am building an app in which the user logs in and shows it's profile, but it crashes immediately when the profile is being shown.

the error:

```
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at com.example.itmaproject.Profile$DownloadStylist.doInBackground(Profile.java:104)
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at com.example.itmaproject.Profile$DownloadStylist.doInBackground(Profile.java:1)
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     ... 4 more
```

the java code

```
private class DownloadStylist extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                Profile.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading profile ...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            Intent i1 = getIntent();
            username = i1.getStringExtra("username");

            List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params1);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Profile JSON: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // profile json object
                jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("user");
                user = new String[jsonarray.length()];
                for (int m = 0; m < jsonarray.length(); m++) {

                    json = jsonarray.getJSONObject(m);

                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    user[m] = json.getString("user");

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            super.onPostExecute(json);
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            try {

                String userid = json.getString("userid");
                String name = json.getString("name");
                String email = json.getString("email");
                String department = json.getString("department");
                String gender = json.getString("gender");
                String ssid = json.getString("ssid");
                String birthdate = json.getString("birthdate");
                String phid = json.getString("phid");

                // displaying all data in textview
                UserId.setText(userid);
                fName.setText(name);
                Email.setText(email);
                // displaying all data in textview
                Add.setText(department);
                Sex.setText(gender);
                Conts.setText(ssid);
                Bday.setText(birthdate);
                txtCredits.setText(phid);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Line 104 is

```
Log.d("Profile JSON: ", json.toString());
```

Comment: Just read it!  `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 15:01:03.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2565):     at com.example.itmaproject.Profile$DownloadStylist.doInBackground(Profile.java:104)`  What is line 104?  My guess is that `userName` is null.  Put a breakpoint on this method, step through and check.  The debuugger will find this in 30 seconds.

Comment: Well you need to investigate why `makeHttpRequest` returns `null`. Any exception in the log before?

Comment: line 104 is "Log.d("Profile JSON: ", json.toString());"

Comment: Haha, do you know how to use the debugger? Serious question btw. That is very helpful in finding these things out :)

Comment: You should always expect to get exceptions and null returns from calls to external resources and handle them properly.  You should also learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: You could also check for the documentation of the method `JSONParser.makeHttpRequest()`. Perhaps it mentions when it returns `null`.